# Allow IIS App pool identity to read foreign process start info

Tags: iis, process, access-rights

Is there a way to grant permissions to the app pool identity to read `Process.StartTime`.
It seems to be limited to access this information only for its own process or for processes it spawned.

My core problem is that I store a process ID but if another process takes its place it causes an issue where I am checking the wrong process. I avoided using the process name in conjunction with PID since it's susceptible to the same problem (only less likely) and thought that StartTime would be a great way of uniquely identifying the process. Unfortunately as I run this from an w3wp worker when I query the process info for the wrong process i get a `Win32Exception` with the text "Access is denied.".

Comment: @JalpaPanchal
1) is not really an option I'm ok with unless I have no other choice.
2) doesn't actually fix the problem, I'm still not allowed to view a foreign process start time just like before. PS: Services don't seem to have a problem accessing the info even if they don't have desktop access.
3) I'm not trying to access the exe file, I'm trying to find out when the exe was started. It wouldn't work. Even if it did work. I'd never know which process is PID squatting. I'd have to grant rights to every exe on that machine and run a service to keep adding rights.